# cordova iOS button event

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, dom-events

I'm trying to make a simple cordova app, and I am trying to include a button event, whereupon when the user clicks it, an alert pops up. However I'm not having any luck so far. I'm pretty sure I've installed all the right plugins for the alert, but still nothing.

Here is my js code:

```
   var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {

        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);

    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        window.analytics.startTrackerWithId('');
        window.analytics.trackView('Hello World');

        


    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },

    



    };

    app.initialize();
```

and here is the html:

```
  <html>
    <head>
        
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">

            <h1>hello</h1>

            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Jump on it</p>
                <p class="event received">Party on wayne</p>

            </div>
            <div>
                 <button id="myBtn" onclick="click()">click</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> function click()=    {alert("clicked");}</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'd be incredibly grateful if anyone could help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call your click-function, that is the problem. A simple example:

```
<button id="myBtn" onclick="app.click()">Click me</button>
```

If your app ist going more complex, you should have an event listener in your javascript, then there is no need to have inline javascript.

Next one: Iy you call an external source like your tracker, you need to whitelisten this source.

Comment: Hi Joerg, I've tried as you suggested. I've tried both inline and external js, to no avail :( I've edited the question to reflect the change you suggested.